# Webcam is in Device Manager, but software doesn't detect it

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I have webcam (Lenovo EasyCamera and USB Video Device (External)) that doesn't detect my PC, but the device is enabled in Device Manager. **Both** of them are **enabled**. If I remove the other webcam it still doesn't work though.

[image]
[image]

I have no idea what causes this, it works the last time I used this but after couple of weeks it doesn't work for some reason.

Here's what it looks like on some programs that needed a webcam.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

When I open Windows Movie Maker Live and did some webcam thing, it worked!
But not on any software just on movie maker...

[image]

Any solution for this stuff? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried updating drivers? Is the problem reproduced on another PC?

Comment: Tried updating the drivers, it's all updated. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: Try removing the device from the device manager. 
Reinstall the webcam drivers.

Comment: @WesleyLachenal : Did you have installed any USB optimization / enhancing utilities in your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the drivers from [A4 TECH PC Camera H Drivers Download](http://www.driverscape.com/download/a4-tech-pc-camera-h), then reboot.
Create first a system restore point so you can undo the installation in case of problems.

If this doesn't work, in the thread
[A4Tech Web cam detection problem with win 7 64bit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7310edda-483b-42c8-bcd5-473c84bd64c8/a4tech-web-cam-detection-problem-with-win-7-64bit?forum=w7itprohardware)
it is said :

> the cam name is A4tech but its real name is Vimicro (zc0301plh) ..and
>   here is the link where u can find the driver u need for 64 bit windows
>   (vista /xp/2000)

The given link was to the page [Vimicro Products Download Center](http://www.vimicro.com/english/product/pc003.htm).
But as the listed drivers are rather old, verify the above by downloading and trying the
[Detection Tool of Vimicro PC Camera Processors Model without notice](http://www.vimicro.com/english/product/ChipTypedetector.zip),
to see if your webcam is really Vimicro.

Answer (score 3):

1. Check this website ([testwebcam.com](http://www.testwebcam.com)) and see if adobe flash player could find and connect to your webcam.
2. Press Win+R and type `dxdiag` and check all the tabs to see if there is any problems with your directx.

I believe this is a directx problem...

Comment: Which website? Missing link?

Comment: Opp... I forgot it ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
Open Facebook and start video chatting with some one. And after the call is answered press FN+F6(key board shortcut for webcam).
It worked for me!!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem might be the driver for the webcam. As it is harder to install drivers in windows 7 and 8 than in previous versions XP/98 due to the institution of Digital Driver Signature Enforcement, here's some step-by-step for you to go off of:

I. Find the correct driver for your webcam on the internet (it is most likely free on Lenovo's website; however, you could use the driver install disc that most likely came with your webcam).

II. Delete the current driver in Device Manager by following the instructions from http://www.pcworld.com/article/246041/how_to_uninstall_drivers_in_windows.html **as are listed below:**

> Click Start, type Device Manager, and press Enter.
> Find and double-click the category of device whose driver you wish to uninstall (for example, the graphics card would be listed under Display Adapters).
> Right-click the device, and click Uninstall.
> Windows will prompt you to confirm the device’s removal. Click OK to remove the driver.
> After the uninstallation is complete, reboot your computer as soon as possible.

III. Follow the following instructions from http://sabrent.com/support/knowledgebase.php?article=14 **as are listed below:**

> 1. During boot-up, continuously press `F8` to get to Advanced Boot Options. Note: On some systems, you need to first press `F2` to go into Boot Menu, then press `F8` to reach Advanced Boot Options.
> 2. When the menu appears, use the DOWN arrow key to scroll to “Disable Driver Signature Enforcement.”
> 3. Press `Enter`.
> 4. Continue the boot process.
> 5. After your computer has completed the boot process, please install the drivers per the included instructions.

IIII. This is how to work around the Driver Signing Enforcement. Then install the driver once your computer has loaded (Note: You must install the driver right after this process. If you do not, you will have to do it all over again.)

Hope this helps! (If it does, accept this as the answer to your question. Thx.)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and literally everything:

- I even did a system restore, rolled back some windows updates, did a hardware troubleshoot and all of that.
- I checked the device manager for imaging devices and it was blank.
- I even tried viewing hidden devices and nothing was detected.

Now, a lot of people will recommend UNINSTALLING the driver in safe mode. DON'T DO IT.

Here's what you do instead. Boot in safe mode. You can do this by pressing down the shift key and clicking the restart option in the start menu.

When you are in safe mode, open device manager. You will be able to view imaging devices (VOILA!!!). Expand and right click on your camera. Select Properties.  Go to the Driver Tab and click on Driver Details.

Now, make a folder in your Documents and copy paste ALL of the Driver files from their original locations in this folder. Make sure you copy the locations they are supposed to be in as well.

Now when you start up in normal mode, go to these locations and CHECK if the driver files exist. My guess is that at least one of them will be missing. Now, copy paste them from the backup you created in Documents in safe mode.
You should now be able to see the imaging devices even in normal mode.